# Using ng-bind-html to assign a form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, forms, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I want to click a button to replace a variable with a form. How do I do this?

#### JavaScript

```
var MainCtrl = angular.module('mainCtrl', []);

MainCtrl.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.bar = 'Foo';
  $scope.foo = function(){
    $scope.bar = '<form class="form-inline" role="form">   <div class="form-group">     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">   </div>   <div class="form-group">     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">   </div>   <div class="checkbox">     <label>       <input type="checkbox"> Remember me     </label>   </div>   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button> </form>';
  }
});

var fooApp = angular.module(
    'fooApp', ['ngSanitize', 'mainCtrl'];
);
```

#### HTML

```
  <body ng-app='fooApp' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="bar"></div>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="foo()">Change bar to form</button>
  </body>
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TQLbVWnfF9G0LVg9tiJl

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very Angular way to do it.

In general, your controllers should *never* contain any markup, nor should they interact directly with the DOM.

I would recommend setting a variable to determine whether or not the button has been clicked, and then using ngShow and ngHide to conditionally display the content or the form.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app='fooApp' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="showForm">Foo</div>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" ng-show="showForm">   <div class="form-group">     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">   </div>   <div class="form-group">     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">   </div>   <div class="checkbox">     <label>       <input type="checkbox"> Remember me     </label>   </div>   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button></form>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="foo()">Change bar to form</button>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
MainCtrl.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.showForm = false;
  $scope.foo = function() {
    $scope.showForm = true;
  }
});
```

And here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMp1JtzpNif4myXix6iu).

Let me know if that meets your needs. There are tons of options to avoid using markup in your controllers.

Comment: No worries, actually taking a look with fresh eyes what I want are different routes. Now just need to figure out how to keep the entire template the same except for one `div` in the left column…

Comment: Just moved my code from ngRouter to ui.router; I think the solution is neigh